# skipping of some scanf in between

Tags: c, char, scanf

In this program the second and forth scanf get skipping , don't know the reason . can some please tell the reason ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 int age;
  char sex,status,city;
   printf("Enter the persons age \n");
   scanf("\n%d",&age);
   printf("enter the gender\n");
   scanf("%c",&sex);
   printf("enter the health status");
   scanf("%c",&status);
   printf("where the person stay city or village");
   scanf("%c",&city);
   if(((age>25)&&(age<35))&&(sex=='m')&&(status=='g')&&(city=='c'))
   printf("42");
   else if(age>25&&age<35&&sex=='f'&&status=='g'&&city=='c')
    printf("31");
    else if(age>25&&age<35&&sex=='m'&&status=='b'&&city=='v')
   printf("60");
  else
  printf("no");

       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reading chars using scanf(), it leaves a newline char in the input buffer.

Change :

```
   scanf("%c",&sex);
   printf("enter the health status");
   scanf("%c",&status);
   printf("where the person stay city or village");
   scanf("%c",&city);
```

to:

```
   scanf(" %c",&sex);
   printf("enter the health status");
   scanf(" %c",&status);
   printf("where the person stay city or village");
   scanf(" %c",&city);
```

Notice the leading whitespace in scanf's format string which tells scanf to ignore whitespaces.

Alternatively, you can use [**getchar()**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/getchar.html) for consuming the newline chars.

```
   scanf("%c",&sex);
   getchar();
   printf("enter the health status");
   scanf("%c",&status);
   getchar();
   printf("where the person stay city or village");
   scanf("%c",&city);
   getchar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I always get the same problem as you using `scanf`, therefore, I use strings instead. I would use:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int age;
    char sex[3],status[3],city[3];
    printf("Enter the persons age \n");
    scanf("\n%d",&age);
    printf("enter the gender\n");
    gets(sex);
    printf("enter the health status");
    gets(status);
    printf("where the person stay city or village");
    gets(city);
    if(((age>25)&&(age<35))&&(sex[0]=='m')&&(status[0]=='g')&&(city[0]=='c'))
        printf("42");
    else if(age>25&&age<35&&sex[0]=='f'&&status[0]=='g'&&city[0]=='c')
        printf("31");
    else if(age>25&&age<35&&sex[0]=='m'&&status[0]=='b'&&city[0]=='v')
        printf("60");
    else
        printf("no");
}
```

If the first `scanf` is still giving you problems (skipping the second question, `gets`), you can use a little trick, but you have to include a new library

```
#include<stdlib.h>
...
char age[4];
...
gets(age);
...
if(((atoi(age)>25)&&(atoi(age)<35))&&(sex[0]=='m')&&(status[0]=='g')&&(city[0]=='c'))
```

And use `atoi` every time you use `age`, because `atoi` converts a char string into an integer (int).